# How to install Yafray for Blender?

Tags: roughness

Please help, i'm trying to do caustics

how do I install Yafaray for blender 2.79? i did as the yafray website instructed but i'm getting this error

[image]

Comment: Why not use Cycles? It can do caustics just fine.

Comment: thank. can you post a good tutorial using cycles in caustics? i can't seem to find one in youtube, tutorials mostly use yafaray.

Comment: Just set up the scene and materials and hit render. If it's too noisy, increase the number of samples (slower) or enable denoising (reduces accuracy, and may cause glitches in some cases).